# Getting text value of anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML

```
{% for song in dj_song_list %}
        <div>
            <p><h3>{{ song.name }}</h3></p>
            <p style="display:none;" class="song_pk">{{ song.id }}</p>
            <button type="button" class='vote' onclick="update(this);">Vote as Favourite</button>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get the text value inside the `p` element with the class `song_pk`

```
function update() {
     console.log($('.song_pk').text());
 }
```

This prints a random long string. How do I get the value of text associated with button I click?

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d43Lr/1/)

Comment: Doesn't work here - http://jsfiddle.net/d43Lr/4/
Instead it prints all the text strings combined.

Comment: I have updated my answer with your fiddle. check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the original JSFiddle posted (http://jsfiddle.net/d43Lr/4/)

A reasonable solution would be for the update function to look something like this

```
function update(element) {
     console.log($(element).siblings('.song_pk').text());
}
```

In the original function, you were finding *all* elements that had a class of "song_pk" - here, we're looking at siblings of the button.

(Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Q9H7T/)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and try:

```
function update(elem) {   // elem is an current element passed on the button click
     console.log($(elem).prev('.song_pk').text()); // will get previous p element text
 }
```

[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d43Lr/5/)

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working but it isn't working on my code for some reason even though my function is exactly the same. It just returns a blank string instead. Any clues on what might be going on?

Comment: Is your `<p>` tag containing value? I mean any text? YOu might get `{{ song.id }}` blank, song.id should be blank

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
  function update(item) {
        var text = $(item).parent().find('p.song_pk').text();
        //or
        var text2 = $(item).prev().text();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function update(e) {
     console.log($(e).prev('.song_pk').text());//It print clicked element prev p text
     console.log($(e).text());//It print clicked element text
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d43Lr/2/)